# Working with Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis

Hi guys I am working on a problem with Lebesgue integration. I believe I have a solution, but I would like to see if it is correct or on the right track.

Problem:
If we have h,k be positive functions on E=[0,1]. We want to show that $\int_E h(x)dx \int_E k(x) dx \geq 1$ given that $h(x)g(x) \geq 1$ for all $x \in E$

Proof:
I think this is a Holder inequality so to say. If we start with the given $h(x)k(x) \geq 1$.
Then we integrate both sides $\int_E h(x)k(x) \geq \int_E 1$.

Which is the same as $\int_E h(x)k(x) \geq 1$. by just integrating the RHS. Now because h and k are positive functions $h(x)k(x)=|h(x)k(x)|$

Thus by holder inequality:
$$\int_E |h(x)k(x)| \leq \big(\int_E |h(x)|^2 \big)^{1/2} \big(\int_E |k(x)|^2 \big )^{1/2}$$
Thus $1 \leq \big(\int_E |h(x)|^2 \big)^{1/2} \big(\int_E |k(x)|^2 \big )^{1/2}$. Then we can square both sides to get rid of the root and by possibility we are done. Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: Suggestion. It's better to leave $[0,1]$ rather than introduce the new notataion $E.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have your order of approximations backwards: you need to have $h$ and $k$ in the integrals, rather than their squares. We know that $h(x)k(x) \geqslant 1 $ implies that $\sqrt{h(x)k(x)} \geqslant 1$, since the square root function is increasing on the non-negative reals.

*Now*, you can use your Hölder's inequality idea: integrating both sides gives
$$ 1=\int_E 1 \leqslant \int_E \sqrt{hk} \leqslant \left( \int_E h^{2/2} \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_E k^{2/2} \right)^{1/2},  $$
and the inequality is retained when you square both sides.